# Can an HTML element have arbitrary attributes?

Tags: html

Can an HTML element be assigned arbitrary attributes?

For example:

```
<div imMakingUpAnAttribute="whatever"></div>
```

Comment: Reopening, as the target dupe was asking whether custom attributes were a good idea, not whether they are possible.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can have custom attributes:

```
<div imMakingUpAnAttribute="whatever"></div>
```

To differentiate between element and custom attributes, a good practice is to prefix it with **`data-`**.

```
<div data-imMakingUpAnAttribute="whatever"></div>
```

Comment: the next answer has me a bit worried about this example, seeing as, according to it, the spec forbids capital letters

Comment: Arbitrary attributes are perfectly valid HTML. Do tools exist that will check your HTML for known attributes for validation? Most likely. But to say that custom attributes are themselves invalid HTML is false. Having said that, it's nevertheless preferable to use data-* attributes instead. That's what they're there for.

Comment: Makes sense. It is not ideal to say not validated just because some tools enforce it.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, but they must be prefixed with `data-`.

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no characters in the range
>   U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).

W3C HTML5 Spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=feed#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

HTML5 custom data attributes post by John Resig 
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

HTML4 attributes
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2